# SQLAlchemy How to check existence of new instance of model in children

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I`m doing a very simple pet-project - Blog with likes under posts.

I`m using async SQLAlchemy 2.0

I have three SQLAlchemy models:

```py
class Reaction(Base):
    __tablename__ = "reaction"

    user_id: Mapped[uuid.UUID] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("user.id"), primary_key=True)
    post_id: Mapped[uuid.UUID] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("post.id"), primary_key=True)
    type: Mapped[Enum[ReactionType]] = mapped_column(Enum(ReactionType))


class User(SQLAlchemyBaseUserTableUUID, Base):
    """
    User model:
        username: Mapped[str]
        ---------------------------
        fastapi_users default columns:
        id: Mapped[UUID_ID]
        email: Mapped[str]
        hashed_password: Mapped[str]
        is_active: Mapped[bool]
        is_superuser: Mapped[bool]
        is_verified: Mapped[bool]
    ---------------------------
    __tablename__ = "user"
    """

    username: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(
        String(length=100), unique=True, index=True, nullable=False
    )
    posts: Mapped[List["Post"]] = relationship("Post", back_populates="owner")


class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = "post"

    id: Mapped[uuid.UUID] = mapped_column(UUID, primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    owner_id: Mapped[uuid.UUID] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("user.id"))
    owner: Mapped["User"] = relationship("User", back_populates="posts", lazy="selectin")
    title: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(200))
    description: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(Text, nullable=True)
    creation_date: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(
        TIMESTAMP, server_default=func.now()
    )
    last_update_date: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(
        TIMESTAMP, server_default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now()
    )
    user_reactions: Mapped[Set["Reaction"]] = relationship(lazy="selectin")
```

**Questions**

1. How to correctly check if some user can "(dis)like" some post or he has "(dis)liked" it before?
2. What is the best way to store post likes and dislikes in in-memory DB?

---

Checking for a row in the `Reaction` table with the specified user_id and post_id is not suitable.

Also i don`t know how to use `user_reactions` correctly.

I tried to create a new instance of `Reaction` with same (as in the table) values and add it to a session, but it still different objects:

```
# Objects with same pk`s
<posts.models.Reaction object at 0x000001F78BE11730>
InstrumentedSet({<posts.models.Reaction object at 0x000001F78BEDC430>})
```

Btw can it possible to replace realted set of **objects** with set of **PK`s**?

For example:

```
# Since this is a many-to-many relationship
InstrumentedSet({'post_id__user_id'})
```

instead of

```
InstrumentedSet({<posts.models.Reaction object at 0x000001F78BEDC430>})
```

Comment: Can't you just add a uniqueness constraint on `user_id` combined with `post_id` in the `reaction` table?

Comment: You mean make a composite key? Is this will replace related set of objects with set of pk`s?